# Why TRESTRequest Execute fail with Timeout Exception on android device?

Tags: android, rest, http, delphi, firemonkey

I have build a firemonkey app to runs on android device but i have some issues with the **Execute** procedure of **TRESTRequest** Class sometimes randomnly fails with **java.net.SocketTimeoutException**. 
I've noticed that when I have the wifi enabled the **RESTRequest1.Execute** is always working correctly but 
on the other hand when i enable the Internet Data on the phone,  i often get **java.net.SocketTimeoutException**.
Why is there a difference between Wifi and Internet Data connection?

I tried with **ExecuteAsync** fuction but i had the same result.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.Active := false;
  Label1.Visible := false;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'customer';
  try
    RESTRequest1.Execute; // java.net.SocketTimeoutException
  except
    Showmessage('FAIL');
  end;
  RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.Active := true;
  Label1.Visible := true;
end;
```

Comment: Mobile data connections are more error prone than WiFi connection. When you don't have strong mobile signal (or it varies), such errors can happen. You can try increasing RESTRequest.Timeout property. Default is 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I increased the timeout to 60 seconds but i got the same exception. I ran the application over a 4G network and the signal was strong at that time.

Comment: This is not Delphi related error, if the timeout increase does not help, and you have good connection, there is very little you can do. Maybe you can find some useful hints here https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3974